# c# passing variables between classes without making them public

Tags: c#, variables

I am writing a WPF application that searches, parses and writes files based on some minimal user input. I have a method call (to a method in another class) in my mainwindow class that requires a number of different pieces of information parsed from two separate files. Currently, I have another method that parses the source files and returns an array of the parsed data for another function of the application. Within that method, I have some public variables to store the necessary info for the first call. This is the only way I can figure how to access those items without writing separate methods to search the parsed data for each individual piece of info I have attached some code to help clarify my current situation:

```
//From mainwindow.xaml.cs

private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
        string[] path = ff.Search(fw.sysName, fw.design, fw.partNumber);//From FileFinder class
        string[] parsedData = fp.Parse(path);//From FileProcessor class
        string[] summary = fw.SummaryWriter(parsedData, fw.masterList);//From FileWriter class
        Output.Text = "";
        foreach (string str in summaryvalues)
        {
            Output.Text += (str + "\n");
        }
    }
```

The variables used in ff.Search() and fw.SummaryWriter() are called from FileWriter.cs:

```
   class FileWriter
   {

    public string sysName;
    public string design;
    public string partNumber;
    public List<string> masterList = new List<string>();

    public string[] MasterWriter(string input, int source)
    {
          //Do stuff. The data for the public variables is mined from this method.

    }

    public string[] SummaryWriter(string[] parsedData, List<string> moduleMasterList)
    {
          //Do stuff
    }
}
```

The question I have is simply, how do I access those variables without making them public?

Comment: All member vars inside the class are accessible by member-methods inside the same class, even if they are private. Am I missing something?

Comment: @lboshuizen Yeah, the're not in the same class.

Comment: @Servy woops, overlooked the diff between ff. and fw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, rather than having public fields how about encapsulating them in public properties that expose private fields? Example:

```
private string somePrivateField;
public string SomePrivateField
{
    get
    {
        return this.somePrivateField;
    }
    set
    {
        this.somePrivateField = value;
    }
}
```

[See this site for info about properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Second, when i run into methods that may need to return multiple values, you can either make out parameters to the method or encapsulate the return values into a class of their own and just return an instance of that class:

```
public void SomeMethod(int inputParameter, out int outvar1, out int outvar2)
{
...
}
```

[See this site for the out keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

or

```
public SomeMethodOutput SomeMethod(int inputParameter)
{
...
return new SomeMethodOutput(number1, number2);
}
```

where SomeMethodOutput is a class with two properties.

Comment: Thanks Steven! The first example you have posted is perfect for what I need. I asked some of the programmers I work with, but their responses, while thorough, lacked a concise example. I think the other examples would work quite well, but for my purposes, could end up being a little clunky.

Answer (score 0):

Make a getter method.

```
class Foo
{
private int _bar;

public void GetBar()
{ return _bar;}
}
```